# How to copy output from a project into startup project's subdirectory?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, plugins, msbuild

I'm creating a plugin for the main app (the startup application) using the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support).

My application (startup app) will search inside its .\Plugins folder for plugins.

- I currently have the main app and the plugin as part of the same solution.
- The main app doesn't include an explicit reference to the plugin project.

The problem is that, obviously, building the solution builds each project to their respective output folders:

- Main\bin\debug\net5
- Plugin\bin\debug\net5

Since the plugin I'm creating is a default plugin, I'd like it to be copied to Main\bin\debug\net5\Plugins\ **always**

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try by specifying output directory on your own? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2019

Comment: @YauvarajRimal That can work, but requires to be set up for every configuration: For Debug, for Release... I would like it to be automatic for every configuration.